# Error using spyOn in a @ViewChild variable

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-decorator

I have a component that uses

```
@ViewChild(NgbDropdown) public dropdown: NgbDropdown;

this.dropdown.isOpen();
```

In my spec file, I need to mock the `isOpen()` result to true but I can't seem to spy on it.

Getting this error:

```
 Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for isOpen()
        Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has something to do with the linter

This is how it should be mocked

```
component.dropdown  = jasmine.createSpyObj(['isOpen']);

(component.dropdown as SpyObj<NgbDropdown>).isOpen.and.returnValue(true);
```

Thanks!